# Date Comparison(string and date) in java

Tags: java

How to compare below two dates in java. my scenario is

```
  String dt1="2013/01/08";
  Date f=Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

  and how to add time(hh:mm:ss.ms) to the date string(i mean to dt1)eg. 2013/01/08 21:10:01.23
```

Comment: I'd start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) for more details on Date objects and Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) method also

```
    String dt1="2013/01/08";
    Date f=Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    System.out.println(sdf.parse(dt1).compareTo(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        String dt1="2013/01/08";
        Date f=Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        System.out.println(sdf.parse(dt1).after(f));
```

- use SimpleDateFormat and format the String into java.util.Date
- use java.util.Date.after() or java.util.Date.before() to compare the two dates